# Laravel - Stripe Integration - Applying a discount coupon to an Invoice object at creation time

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I´m trying to apply a Stripe Coupon to a Stripe Invoice object at creation time in my Laravel 5.8 application, with no luck so far.
This is the code in my controller:

```
$options = [
    'api_key' => 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'stripe_version' => "2019-08-14"
];

$coupon = \Stripe\Coupon::retrieve('xfpwySG1'); // I´m retrieving the coupon solely to use it for testing.

// $parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id]; // This works fine (no discounts applied)
//This are all the different versions of parameters array I´ve tried, none of them work
// $parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, ['discounts' => ['coupon' => 'xfpwySG1']] ]; //Invalid array
// $parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, 'discounts' => ['coupon' => 'xfpwySG1'] ]; //Invalid array
// $parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, 'discounts' => ['coupon' => $coupon] ]; //Invalid array
// $parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, 'discounts' => ['coupon' => 'xfpwySG1'] ]; //Invalid array
// $parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, 'discounts' => $coupon ]; //Invalid array
// $parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, ['discounts' => ['xfpwySG1']] ]; //Invalid object
$parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, ['discounts' => 'xfpwySG1'] ]; //Invalid object
// $parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, 'discounts' => ['xfpwySG1'] ]; //Invalid object
// $parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, 'discounts' => 'xfpwySG1' ]; //Invalid array

// This is where I create the invoice object, using the info above.
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::create($parameters, $options);
```

Notice if I don´t try to include the 'discounts' parameter, as in the first $parameters line, everything works fine; just as soon as I try to give away free stuff, my app fails... haha! Also, I tried applying the coupon to the InvoiceItem object, with similar results.

I´m having some difficulties understanding the Stripe Ecosystem and how all the pieces fit together, so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should use an array of array for 'discounts' key. Try this.

```
$parameters = ['customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id, [['coupon' => 'xfpwySG1', 'discount' => null]];
```